# Toggleable on click tooltip from dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get a tooltip to open or close (toggle) based when clicked on.

The HTML is generated dynamically from javascript but here is an example of one of the elements that I want to have a tooltip when clicked:

```
<label class="passiveText smallText" title="Name: Smith, John , Occupation Code: BA81, Occupation 
Description: BUSINESS SYSTEMS M" rel="tooltip" style="margin-top:10px; width:80%; text-decoration:underline; 
color:#009245;" containeridx="0" id="lblBadge_7022_0">7022</label>
```

On the page show I am trying to add the following code so when clicked

```
    $(document).on("pageshow", "#DailyFrm", function () {
        $('[id*="lblBadge"]').on('click', function (e) {
            $(this).tooltip('open');
        });
    }
```

This isn't even getting the the tooltip to open in the first place. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this jQuery mobile? 'pageshow' is not a valid event for desktop jQuery

Comment: Sorry, yes this is jQuery mobile. I'll update the tag

Comment: Are you using any tooltip plugin or want to implement this by yourself?

Comment: Have you tried swapping out `click` with `tap`?

Comment: I am not using any additional plugins. Just jQuery, jQueryUI, jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Switching click for tap had no effect.

Comment: `id^=` try it..`^` starts with "lblBadge".

Comment: Well, it does appear the element is not getting selected (using * or ^). CSS changes don't work either.

Comment: Then your js code isn't loaded. Are you using a single or a multi page model? Where you placing js code?

Comment: Single page model... and this code is in the same file that is correctly generating the above HTML...

Comment: Place that code inside page div, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited

### Styleless implementation of the tooltip ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf2fy/)) for your html:

```js
$('[id*="lblBadge"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $tooltip = $this.children('.tooltip');

    if ($tooltip.length > 0) {
        $tooltip.remove();

        return true;
    } 

    $tooltip = $('<div>');
    $tooltip.addClass('tooltip');
    $tooltip.text( $this.attr('title') );

    $this.append($tooltip);
});
```

And styles:

```
label { // choose appropriate selector
    position: relative; // required for positioning
    overflow: visible; // required for guaranteed tooltip visibility
}

.tooltip {
    position: absolute; // required for positioning

    // Relative to the parent label
    top: 35px;
    left: 20px;

    // Not necessary but recommended for the good look
    width: 250px;

    // optional
    background: lightgray;
    color: black;
}
```

---

I'm recommend to use beautiful solution provided by Osvaldas Valutis: http://osvaldas.info/elegant-css-and-jquery-tooltip-responsive-mobile-friendly

Check [live demo](http://osvaldas.info/examples/elegant-css-and-jquery-tooltip-responsive-mobile-friendly/) from mobile.